# Accessing Context in an IMessageMutator implementer?

Tags: aop, soa, nservicebus

How can I access the current context from within a message mutator?

I also need to have access to the saga data.

I want to pass certain data transparently from both the sender and implementers (handlers). This data will be set in the outgoing headers. Depending on the situation, if the handler is of type Saga, I want to set some of these properties into the saga data.

Later when a call "ReplyToOriginator" is detected, I want to grab the values from saga and set it back into the headers of the reply message.

So how can I do this from within the message mutator?

All the examples I have seen so far seems to indicate that it has access only to the message and not context.

Comment: Access to headers, handler, UoW and saga data. You know the standard stuff usually known as execution "context"

Comment: Alwyn, can you open a github issue on what you're trying to do so that the core team can engage in a deeper discussion on different ways to support what you're trying to achieve? https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/new

Comment: Why would you want to do that from the Mutator? Kind of violates the SRP don't you think?

Comment: @stephenl not exactly. Checkout Postsharp, DI container with AoP, PolicyInjection etc. They all give you access to the ambient context.