# AoP support in NServiceBus?

Tags: c#, .net, aop, nservicebus, soa

Ties back to my old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225486/accessing-context-in-an-imessagemutator-implementer):

But I really want to intercept messages AND have an instance of the handler and be able to influence the whether the message should go to the handler at all. Basically an "around advice".

Now the most  traditional way of implementing something like this is via dynamic inheritance of the target object and overriding the virtual methods. The thing that I could not tell due to lack of documentation whether, NServiceBus creates or builds up its message handler instances. If it builds up, then it can't dynamically inherit, so most AoP framework is probably out of the question, otherwise most popular DI container should do the trick.

However testing with Saga handers it seems like NServiceBus builds up rather than creates new due to the requirement for a default constructor, which points to NServiceBus manually activating the class.

Yes I realize I can use good ole' OOP to solve the same problem, but I usually prefer AoP for better (less) coupling.

---

Comment: I don't think this is really a NServiceBus issue. NServiceBus uses a IoC container under the cover (and you can switch the IoC implementation if you like) and most IoC containers will allow you to intercept or decorate the creation of types. With NServiceBus, you probably want to decorate your message handlers.

Answer (score 6):

If all you want to do is influence if a message should go to a handler or not, then NServiceBus provides a solution for that => `DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers()`

You can create a generic handler and set it up to fire before any other handlers.

```
public class SomeHandler: IHandleMessages<object>, ISpecifyMessageHandlerOrdering
{
    public IBus Bus {get;set;}

    public void Handle(object message)
    {
        Bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers();
    }

    public void SpecifyOrder(Order order)
    {
        order.SpecifyFirst<SomeHandler>();
    }
}
```

For more details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4100362/136720) answer

Alternatively, this can be plugged in as a mutator

```
class StopThePipelineMutator: IMutateIncomingTransportMessages,INeedInitialization
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void MutateIncoming(TransportMessage transportMessage)
    {
        Bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers();    
    }

    public void Init()
    {
       Configure.Component<StopThePipelineMutator>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but someone looking for a way to get AOP with NServiceBus, here's a different way of doing it:

https://github.com/MeTitus/NServiceBus/commit/278b6bf4e3daba2fbdfc5295b8718609946d653d

The other way is to user PostSharp.